# Unable to decrypt pgp file using command line

Tags: pgp

I tried to decrypt pgp files somes are getting correctly decrypted but others are still having problem for decryption.

Command which i am using for decryption is :

```
pgp -z pass_phrase D:\PGP_FILES\file1.pgp -o D:\PGP_FILES\DecryptedFile
```

Its output :

```
Pretty Good Privacy(tm) Version 6.5.1
(c) 1999 Network Associates Inc.
Uses the RSAREF(tm) Toolkit, which is copyright RSA Data Security, Inc.
Export of this software may be restricted by the U.S. government.

File is encrypted.  Secret key is required to read it.

Key for user ID: User <mail_id>
1024-bit RSA key, Key ID 0xABC, created date
Key can sign.
```

And stops after several minutes.

After the decryption is started output file is getting created and also its size is increasing till the end phase but after completion of decryption file is getting deleted automatically.

I am not getting reason behind the problem. So can anybody please help me come out of this situation? What is the exact problem?

Comment: PGP 6.5.1 is _horribly_ out of date. Try using a newer version or the free software equivalent GnuPG.

Comment: but its GUI application and i want command line tool so that i can write program using it.

Comment: GnuPG _is_ a command line tool. There are graphical user interfaces for it, but these are neither called GnuPG nor included when installing it (unless you install some GnuPG distribution that includes both GnuPG and a GUI).

Comment: Hi Jens, Thanks for your help. Its showing the error as file integrity is broken and thats why cannot completely decrypt file..

Comment: If the files are broken, you're probably out of luck. Have the sender verify the files he sent and if they're fine, send them again.